# HTML: div doesn't stretch out?

Tags: html, css, block

According to this website

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

a div is a block element and "a block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can)."

Then why does this code not color the upper part of the page red?:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
    
    </style>
    
    
</head>
    
<body>
    
    
    <div style="background: red;float: left; height: 20%;"></div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

When I add "width = 100%" to the style of the div, I get what I expect without that variable. Why doesn't it stretch out by itself?

Comment: 1) Your container is empty. Add content and you will see something. 2) You've added `float: left` so the normal block element properties no longer apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A floated empty div has no height or width.

You've given it a height, but it still has zero width. Only when it also has a width (or some content) will you see it.

The default block behaviour you've referenced doesn't apply to a floated element.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `float: left` in there (which only takes the width of its content and wouldn't make any sense for 100% width anyway) - just remove it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: grey;
        }
    
    
    </style>
    
    
</head>
    
<body>
    
    
    <div style="background: red;height: 20%;"></div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to stretch out the floated div element, the styling for its width must be explicitly stated.  If you neglect to specify it, then the browser only stretches it as much as it needs. So, either adding `width="100%"`to the DIV tag or adding `width:100%` to the its styling are options so that  the floated div occupies the full width, even if it lacks content.

The source that the OP cites applies to an "unfloated" div element.  But, a div that is floated, as is the case in the OP's CSS code, does not follow the usual rules per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

> ...the element is taken from the normal flow of the web page, though
>   still remaining a part of the flow ...

In this particular case, since the OP indicates that the floated div should stretch out completely, it seems superfluous to have the div float left; that float property should probably be deleted unless the OP expects the width to dynamically change at some point.

Another way to stretch out the div element is to add this CSS to its styling: `display:flex` which creates a [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    div {
    background: red; 
    height: 20%;
    display:flex;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>


  <div></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Note: while I removed the float property for the flex-box, you may leave it as it will have no effect on the flex-box.

Comment: I was getting all set to downvote your reply based on your first paragraph. You should state there that you are talking about floated elements.

Comment: @Rob: Thank you for your feedback.